# Find Max Numbers

Tags: java

Problem Name
Find Max
Problem Statement

You are given an integer array  A of the length N and an integer K. You have to remove all the elements from the array one by one and you can only remove from the first or the last element of the remaining array. If you have removed  elements, then the value of a variable ans  is given by the following:

```
Val = element of the array which you are going to remove.
if x is even
    ans+=val;
else
    ans-=val;
```

You are required to maximize the value of the variable ans. Also, you can change the sign of at most K  elements.
Note: Initially, the value of ans is  0.
Input format
First line: Two space-separated integers  and 
Second line:  space-separated integers denoting the array 
Output format
Print the maximum possible value of ans.

```
1≤N≤100
1≤K≤N
10-9≤Ai≤109
Sample Input(.txt)
4 2
5 1 2 3
Sample Output(.txt)
11
```

```
package com.java.simple;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class FindMax {

    public static int N;

    public static int K;

    public static int[][][][] dp = new int[101][101][101][2];

    public static int[] a = new int[101];

    public static int solve(int i, int j, int k, int p) {
        int ans = 0;
        if (i > j || k > K) {
            return 0;
        } else if (dp[i][j][k][p] != -1) {
            return dp[i][j][k][p];
        } else {
            if (p == 0) {
                ans = Math.max(a[i] + solve(i + 1, j, k, 1), Math.max(a[j] + solve(i, j - 1, k, 1),
                        Math.max(-a[i] + solve(i + 1, j, k + 1, 1), -a[j] + solve(i, j - 1, k + 1, 1))));
            } else {
                ans = Math.max(-a[i] + solve(i + 1, j, k, 0), Math.max(-a[j] + solve(i, j - 1, k, 0),
                        Math.max(a[i] + solve(i + 1, j, k + 1, 0), a[j] + solve(i, j - 1, k + 1, 0))));
            }
        }
        dp[i][j][k][p] = ans;
        return ans;
    }

    public static int Main() {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        N = sc.nextInt();
        K = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.arraycopy(dp, -1, (Integer.SIZE / Byte.SIZE), K, N);
        int ans = solve(0, N - 1, 0, 0);
        System.out.print(ans);
        System.out.print("\n");
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FindMax.Main();
    }
}
```

```
4 2

5 1 2 3

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayStoreException

    at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)

    at com.java.simple.FindMax.Main(FindMax.java:43)

    at com.java.simple.FindMax.main(FindMax.java:51)
```

Comment: you should consult the official documentation, like [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int)) - many errors in calling that method

Answer (score 1):

```
void java.lang.System.arraycopy(Object src, int srcPos, Object dest, int destPos, int length)
```

> Copies an array from the specified source array, beginning at the specified position, to the specified position of the destination array.

The third param in this method is supposed to be an array not an `int`.

Comment: and the next Exception probably would be "`IndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown and the destination is not modified: 

    The srcPos argument is negative. " - according documentation: [arraycopy](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,int,java.lang.Object,int,int))